# Does a blank field of type Double in Ms Access occupy Space

Tags: ms-access

I have developed a software using Ms Access as the backend. I sometimes have to dynamically create 150 columns (at Max). However, not all of these 150 columns are always occupied so out of 150 some times only 5 fields may be populated and the rest remain blank or are filled with 0 ***(I do not have control over the external data source that is used to populate my DB)***.

So my query is, does a blank field of the type double occupy any space? if yes how much? will this impact the file size? Also what is the space consumed by 0 in a double field? 8 bytes or less?

The reason I have this query is because my db is getting to 2GB really fast and I suspect this could be the reason.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, yes. All fields occupy space.

A double is a fixed-size field which takes 64-bit (= 8 bytes), plus a little overhead to store nulls.

All fields except *Short Text*, *Long Text*, *Attachment* and *OLE Object* are fixed size, which means they take their full size for every row, independent of what's actually stored in the field.

A properly normalized database should not store lots of nulls, but instead store the data relationally.

Comment: Thanks Erik, I shall try eliminating or temporarily reducing the columns only to the ones that are required. Then shall check if this solves the issue and will mark your comment as the right answer.